# Web Scraping List Index Out Of Range

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = "https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_nr_p_36_4?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A976419031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Ck%3Amobile%2Cp_36%3A1318507031&keywords=mobile&ie=UTF8&qid=1543902909&rnid=1318502031"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
raw_html= uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(raw_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"s-item-container"})

filename = "Product.csv"
f = open (filename , "w")

headers = "Name,Price,Prime \n"
f.write(headers)

for container in containers:

    title_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"a-row a-spacing-mini"})
    product_name = title_container[0].div.a.h2.text

    price = container.findAll("span",{"class":"a-size-small a-color-secondary a-text-strike"})
    product_price = price[0].text.strip()

    prime = container.findAll("i",{"class":"a-icon a-icon-prime a-icon-small s-align-text-bottom"})
    product_prime = prime[0].text

    print("product_name : " + product_name)
    print("product_price : " + product_price)
    print("product_prime : " + product_prime)

    f.write(product_name + "," + product_price + "," + product_prime + "\n") 
f.close
```

I wrote my first web scraping code but for some reason it only looped for 4 times and showed a error msg that  (File "firstwebscrapping.py", line 23, in 
product_price = price[0].text.strip()
IndexError: list index out of range).
Please, can someone explain where I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is not every item have the original price and current price, so you can modify this code.

From `"class":"a-size-small a-color-secondary a-text-strike"`

To `"class":"a-size-base a-color-price s-price a-text-bold"`

And another issue will raise from this code

`containers = target[0].findAll("div",{"class":"s-item-container"})`

s-item-container not only in ajaxData but also in atfResults, so we use the select function to get the target div list use this code `target = page_soup.select('div#atfResults')`, hope this can solve your question.

`div#search-main-wrapper> div#ajaxData> s-item-container 
 div#search-main-wrapper> div#atfResults> s-item-container`

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = "https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_nr_p_36_4?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A976419031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Ck%3Amobile%2Cp_36%3A1318507031&keywords=mobile&ie=UTF8&qid=1543902909&rnid=1318502031"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
raw_html= uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(raw_html, "html.parser")

target = page_soup.select('div#atfResults')
containers = target[0].findAll("div",{"class":"s-item-container"})

filename = "Product.csv"
f = open (filename , "w")

headers = "Name,Price,Prime \n"
f.write(headers)
print(len(containers))
for container in containers:

    title_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"a-row a-spacing-mini"})
    product_name = title_container[0].div.a.h2.text

    price = container.findAll("span",{"class":"a-size-base a-color-price s-price a-text-bold"})
    product_price = price[0].text.strip()

    prime = container.findAll("i",{"class":"a-icon a-icon-prime a-icon-small s-align-text-bottom"})
    product_prime = prime[0].text

    print("product_name : " + product_name)
    print("product_price : " + product_price)
    print("product_prime : " + product_prime)

    f.write(product_name + "," + product_price + "," + product_prime + "\n") 
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not every `container` has `<span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary a-text-strike">`.

So when you find those elements:

```
price = container.findAll("span",{"class":"a-size-small a-color-secondary a-text-strike"})
```

And there are no elements found - the `price` is an empty list. In the next line you access the fist element of `price`:

```
product_price = price[0].text.strip()
```

And because `price` is empty, you get an error `IndexError: list index out of range`.

For example, I have such elements on the page from link in the code:

[image]

You select strikethrough price, but *OnePlus 6T* doesn't have it. It only has `<span class="a-size-base a-color-price s-price a-text-bold">`.

You can check if `price` is empty, and if so - you can search the price in that `span` above.