# Web scraping: Index out of Bound (Possible scaling error)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi Wrote a web scraping program and it gets the ASN number correctly, but after all the data is scraped, it returns a error "Array Out if Bounds".

I am using Pycharm and latest python version. Below is my code.
There is already a similar issue on stackoverflow but I am not able to get the pieces together and make it work. ([Web Scraping List Index Out Of Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646367/web-scrapping-list-index-out-of-range)) its the exact same error but I am not sure how to get it working for my List.

Error seems to be at current_country = link.split('/')[2]
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
import re
import json


url = 'https://ipinfo.io/countries'
SITE = 'https://ipinfo.io'

def url_to_soup(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    html = opener.open(req)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return soup


def find_pages(page):
    pages = []
    for link in page.find_all(href=re.compile('/countries')):
        pages.append(link.get('href'))
    return pages


def scrape_pages(links):
    mappings = {}

    print("Scraping Pages for ASN Data...")

    for link in links:
        country_page = url_to_soup(SITE + link)
        current_country = link.split('/')[2]
        print(current_country)
        for row in country_page.find_all('tr'):
            columns = row.find_all('td')
            if len(columns) > 0:
                current_asn = re.findall(r'\d+', columns[0].string)[0]
                print(current_asn)
                """
                name = columns[1].string
                routes_v4 = columns[3].string
                routes_v6 = columns[5].string
                mappings[current_asn] = {'Country': current_country,
                                     'Name': name,
                                     'Routes v4': routes_v4,
                                     'Routes v6': routes_v6}
      return mappings """


main_page = url_to_soup(url)

country_links = find_pages(main_page)
#print(country_links)

asn_mappings = scrape_pages(country_links)
print(asn_mappings)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last `href` contains string "`/countries`" in https://ipinfo.io/countries is actually "`/countries`":

```html
<li><a href="/countries">Global ASNs</a></li>
```

After splitting this link, it produced list `["", "countries"]` where the third element was missing. To fix this problem, simply check the list length before retrieving the third element:

```py
        ...
        current_country = link.split('/')
        if len(current_country) < 3:
            continue
        current_country = current_country[2]
        ...
```

Another solution is to exclude the last `href` by changing the regexp to:

```py
    ...
    for link in page.find_all(href=re.compile('/countries/')):
        ...
```

Comment: I am trying to get the data "REGISTRY" and "IP ADDRESS" by passing the each ASN Id (https://ipinfo.io/AS6984).  I am not sure how to write a regex. I am trying to do is print(abc.find_all('div')) which is not working.